# Regular expression with Azure DevOps task extension

Tags: regex, azure-devops-extensions

We're updating our azure virtual machine task extension with disk management. A multiline field to let user provide label, letter and size of their data disks with newline and semicolons to separate items and disks. Like this :

"Database Disk";F;30

"Temp Database Disk";G;30

"Logs Database";H;15E

Here is task.json :

```
{
  "name": "NewDataDisks",
  "type": "multiLine",
  "label": "Data Disks",
  "required": false,
  "groupName": "Disks",
  "visibleRule": "AddDataDisk = true",
  "defaultValue": "\"Database Disk\";F;30\n\"Temp Database Disk\";G;30\n\"Logs Database\";H;15",
  "helpMarkDown": "Provide list of data disks with disk label, mount letters and disk capacity separated by a semicolon :\n\n \"Database Disk\";F;30\n\"Temp Database Disk\";G;30\n\"Logs Database\";H;15 \n\n Each virtual machine size has a max of data disks attached which can't be check in here. During release execution, a check will be done.",
  "validation": {
    "expression": "isMatch(value, '(^\"[a-z A-Z]+\";[a-zA-Z]{1};([1-9]+[0-9]+|[1-9]+)$)','Multiline')",
    "message": "[Enter a valid datadisks list](https://regex101.com/r/WeDgsJ/1)"
  }
}
```

Problem is validation will pass if at least one line is matching. But I'd like a full match for every line but I struggle finding how with regex. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does `'^"[a-z A-Z]+";[a-zA-Z];[1-9][0-9]*(?:\r?\n"[a-z A-Z]+";[a-zA-Z];[1-9][0-9]*)*$'` work for you? Not sure you need `'Multiline'`.

Comment: You can try adding `\\A your expression \\Z`, `\A` always matches the start of the input, not just the line, `\Z` the end of the input.

Comment: I see, I posted the full answer.

Comment: Hey regex masters, would it be possible to check letter unicity across lines ? We want each disk with its unique letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `'Multiline'` option (since you need to treat the string as a whole text, not as a line-per-line text) and use

```
'^"[a-z A-Z]+";[a-zA-Z];[1-9][0-9]*(?:\r?\n"[a-z A-Z]+";[a-zA-Z];[1-9][0-9]*)*$'
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `"` - a `"` char
- `[a-z A-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters or space
- `";` -  `";` substring
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `;` - a semi-colon
- `[1-9][0-9]*` - a non-zero digit and then zero or more digits
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing "container" group:

  - `\r?\n` - CRLF or LF line ending
  - `"[a-z A-Z]+";[a-zA-Z];[1-9][0-9]*` - same patterns as above
- `)*` - end of the group, repeat zero or more times
- `$` - end of string.